# How do I save an array of arrays to userDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, userdefaults

I'm trying to save an array of arrays of integers, which are used as a code to keep track of images. A user can upload images from the photo library and save them to different sections of the collection view (thus different sections of the array). When you open the app, you can only successfully save images to the first section (tops). When you refresh the app, only the photos from "tops" remain, nothing else. Additionally, after refreshing, I can no longer save images to userdefaults at all. Am I missing something?

```
var currentImageType = String()
// USER DEFAULTS
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var images: [[Int]] = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myKey") as? [[Int]] ?? [[0], [1000], [2000], [3000], [4000]]

class ViewController: UIViewController, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    // access photo library
    @objc private func addPhotos(categoryType: String) {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.selectionLimit = 100
        config.filter = .images
        let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
        currentImageType = categoryType
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        results.forEach { result in
            group.enter()
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { reading, error in
                defer {
                    group.leave()
                }
                guard let image = reading as? UIImage, error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                // saving an image to database

                func saveByType(Type: Int) {
                    // USER DEFAULTS
                    images[Type].append(images[Type].last! + 1)
                    print(images)
                    LocalFileManager.instance.saveImage(image: image, imageName: String(images[Type].last!), folderName: "closet")
                    userDefaults.set(images, forKey: "myKey")
                }
                
                switch currentImageType {
                case "tops": saveByType(Type: 0)
                case "outerwear": saveByType(Type: 1)
                case "bottoms": saveByType(Type: 2)
                case "singles": saveByType(Type: 3)
                case "accessories": saveByType(Type: 4)
                default: saveByType(Type: 0)
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I followed a few examples online, and it looks like my code is in line with it (for the most part at least). Not sure what I'm missing, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: While user defaults are a handy way of saving data, they are not intended to provide complex data storage.  I suggest you look at Core Data.

Comment: LocalFileManager.instance.saveImage(image: image, imageName: String(images[Type].last!), folderName: "closet"); u saving image local folder also so why not get image from there>?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII I'm also retrieving images from the local manager. Now I'm trying to figure out how to load all uploaded images from previous sessions

Comment: you just have to store the name of images in user defaults array of string and get that image from document folder with that name

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII that's what I'm trying to figure out! It seems like the user defaults are only ever storing the first image I upload, not the following.

Comment: from where you copy the code ?

Comment: if you wanna just store image and get them I have simple solution for this